# SDK platform - tools don't exist

Tags: android, android-sdk-manager

I have a problem installing the platform-tools via the Android SDK manager.

I searched in some other forums for related questions and the answer was to add it via the SDK Manager option in eclipse with :

`Windows -> Android SDK Manager -> select needed tools -> install`.

But the only tool i see at Tools is Android SDK Tools which is already installed. Checking for updates doesn't change anything.

Somebody please help.

Answer (score 0):

Download this http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html and you don't have any problems.

Comment: it tried that one too. But then the location for the SDK couldn't be found,even if I selected the SDK-folder.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is already installed ... Did you check the checkboxes at the bottom of SDK Manager ? You can choose to display or hide new/installed/obsolete packages.

Comment: It doesn't change anything.
But I noticed when starting the manager the xmls couldn't be loaded in the log and this error occurs: "IO Unknown Host dl-ssl.google.com"

Comment: Are you using windows or linux ? Do you have a specific network configuration (proxy) ?